# Find device Ubuntu Core 20 image to reinstall

Tags: lenovo, snap, ubuntu-core

I am using a device that is the Lenovo ThinkEdge SE30.  It came with Ubuntu Core 20.  I want to reinstall this image on the device.

When I check the properties of it I see the following:
[image]

The "model" has the value of "lenovo-wwan".  When I look at the link https://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-core/20/stable/current/ I cannot find anything that states "lenovo" there.  I am looking for:

- ubuntu-core-20-lenovo-wwan.img.xz
- ubuntu-core-20-lenovo-wwan.img.xz.zsync
- ubuntu-core-20-lenovo-wwan.manifest
- ubuntu-core-20-lenovo-wwan.model-assertion

My question is:

- Where can I find this specific "lenovo-wwan" Ubuntu Core 20 image?

Answer (score 0):

There's not a version of Ubuntu for your specific device or even for Lenovo devices.

Use the image that corresponds with the CPU architecture of your device. Your choices are AMD64, ARM64, and ARMhf.

If you don't know what architecture your CPU supports, consult the documentation for your CPU model.

Comment: The hardware, using "cat /proc/cpuinfo" is "11th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-1115GRE @ 3.00GHz", so AMD64.

I wonder with is the difference between the teo AMD64: "ubuntu-core-20-amd64+intel-iot" vs "ubuntu-core-20-amd64".

Comment: Intel IoT is optimised for Intel IoT SoCs.  See: https://ubuntu.com/download/iot/intel-iot

Comment: Thank you, I can see that when I mouse over all the "Download" links on that page, they all point to ubuntu-core-22-amd64+intel-iot.img.xz.

Answer (score 0):

### Ubuntu Core 20 image to reinstall

For Ubuntu recommendations for Lenovo ThinkEdge SE30 See:

https://ubuntu.com/certified/202104-28914

The main difference I can see between  ubuntu-core-22-amd64.img.xz and ubuntu-core-22-amd64+intel-iot.img.xz is the size of the snaps folder and kernel version.

[image]

The kernel folder shows kernel versions which are now the same for Core 20 and Core 22.

[image]

Comment: So this link just shows what is certified for this device and it looks like the latest version is Ubuntu Core 20.

Why is not Ubuntu Core 22 not certified?

Also, would it be: **ubuntu-core-20-amd64+intel-iot.img.xz** or **ubuntu-core-20-amd64.img.xz**?

Comment: @Kris: I think Core 22 is still a bit preliminary. I have tried both of the images you reference and so far have not seen many differences. I have edited the answer.

Comment: Thank you, I installed both to try.

Comment: @Kris: Please let us know your results. Interesting subject.